Is there an easy example of a non-torsion class in $H^2_{ét}(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$ when $X$ is affine but not integral?
It is known that for an affine scheme $X=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$, there is a natural injection $\operatorname{Br}(X)\to H^2_{ét}(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$, which lands into the torsion part of the cohomological Brauer group. I'm trying to find an easy example of $R$ such that $H^2_{ét}(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$ is not torsion.
I found an example in Grothendieck's "Le groupe de Brauer II", which uses an example of Mumford of some normal but not regular complex surface which has a point with a weird local Picard group which ensures some non-torsion. (This example is the one referred to in Milne, and this in turn is referenced by Wikipedia.) The counter-example is really not easy to understand.
It seems to me that the reason why we need a complicated example is that people are trying to find one such that $X$ is integral ($R$ is a domain). Is there an easy to understand example if we don't put any hypothesis on $R$?

I may be mistaken, but to my knowledge the group $H^2_{ét}(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$ is also called Taylor's bigger Brauer group. Maybe those key words are of help (in case that you are not aware of this name). It is for example studied by Stefan Schröer in https://www.math.uni-duesseldorf.de/~schroeer/publications_pdf/brauer.pdf. Although I did not check, the title of this paper suggests that you can maybe find an example in here.

Thanks for the reference! I understand that this paper proves that under some mild hypotheses (always satisfied by affine schemes) the cohomological $H^2$ can be described in terms of a generalization of Azumaya algebras, which do not have to be unital or projective. So this could be a direction if it's easy to find an example of such an algebra whose which is not torsion in this "Taylor group", and if it's also doable to explicitly understand what the cohomology class associated to it is.
